# Firebase Analytics not showing data

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-analytics

I made an app which is connected with firebase analytics. when i create my app first it was working fine and data is showing in firebase analytics dashboard, till nov 5 it was working fir but now there is no data showing in dashboard. I remove everything and again set firebase in app but Its not working.
I check to connect new project with firebase same as my old project but it is working.

Please tell me how i can find where is the issue.

1st I do this   id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.4.0" apply false in project level gradle file

then i set implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")

Please tell me how i can solve this issue